# ZSH - Variable Expansion Dilemma

Tags: zsh, expansion

I am using ZSH, and I believe I need to use variable expansion to solve my problem, but I'm not entirely sure.

```
FOOFIELD=1
PROPERTY=FOO

echo ${(P)PROPERTYFIELD}
```

Expected Result: 1

Current Result: null

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've also tried this:
`echo ${${PROPERTY}FIELD}`
but it yields:
`zsh: bad substituion`

Comment: Found it!
`echo ${(P)$(echo ${PROPERTY}FIELD)}`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by executing the below commands

```
➜  ~   FOOFIELD=1
➜  ~   FOO=11
➜  ~   PROPERTY=FOO
➜  ~   echo ${(P)PROPERTY}
11
➜  ~   echo ${${(P)PROPERTY}FIELD}
1
```